# Вызов функции С++ из памяти С#

Tags: c#, memory

Здравствуйте! Возникла следующая проблема: появилась необходимость вызвать функцию из приложения, написанного на С++, путём вызова ее из памяти (если, конечно, это возможно) на С#. Функция в оригинале выглядит примерно так:

```
void Send(int Index, int SubIndex, const char* Message)
{
    // Some code
}
```

Указатель в памяти на эту функцию я могу получить. Достаточно ли этой информации для ее вызова и как это можно сделать?

Comment: А как нужная вам функция оказалась в памяти? Загрузилась с каким-то c++-приложением, или как-то иначе?

Comment: @selya Это не моё приложение. Но мне известны входные данные функции, а также я могу найти в памяти адрес ее вхождения

Comment: @selya А так - да. Она загружается в память вместе с запуском С++ приложения. С одинаковым относительным адресом. Так что трудностей в ее поиске нет

Comment: Стойте-стойте. Расскажите о том, что именно вы делаете. Ваше приложение на C#? Откуда в нём код на C++ и почему вы не можете его вызвать напрямую? Или этот код в _другом_ приложении?

Comment: @VladD Это другое приложение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если функция загружена в вашем приложении, тогда так:

```
delegate int SendDelegate(int Index, int SubIndex, IntPtr Message);

int Send(int index, int subIndex, string message)
{
    IntPtr funcPointer = ...; // здесь адрес вашей функции
    var func = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<SendDelegate>(funcPointer);
    IntPtr lpstr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(message); // выделяем память под char*
    int result = func(index, subIndex, lpstr);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lpstr); // освобождаем память
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую, скоро отпишусь

Comment: Хм. Приложение вылетело без объяснения причин хД

Comment: Видимо, я что-то напутал с адресом, так что помечу как ответ хД

Comment: У вас одно приложение, и в нем выполняется .NET код и C++ код?

Comment: Увидел ваш комментарий к вопросу... Если это другое приложение, тогда мой способ не подойдет, там намного сложнее все делается. Приложение вылетело потому, что адреса верны только в контексте одного процесса, если вы возьмете корректный адрес с процесса 1, и попробуете его использовать в процессе 2, он может указывать в никуда.

Comment: А у вас нет где-нибудь подобного примера?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov В меня нет, но там будет очень сложно. Вам придется написать длл-ку на C++, которая экспортирует 1 функцию (которая вызывает метод Send), потом в c# коде вы создаете поток внутри другого процесса при помощи CreateRemoteThreadEx, и вызываете удаленно функцию LoadLibrary с вашей длл. Дальше нужно выбрать каким образом вы будете сообщать другому процессу, что нужно вызывать функцию Send (TCP/пайпы/SendMessage/events) и отсылать данные с C# в длл-ку. Потом длл-ка будет вызывать Send

Comment: Есть способ попроще, если вам известен адрес функции, вы можете создать код вызова Send в памяти в C# программе (именно команды процессора в виде массива байтов), и потом через CreateRemoteThreadEx запускать этот код внутри другого процесса. Но этот способ не сработает, если в Windows включен DEP.

Comment: ух, спасибо за идеи! Буду разбираться!